# Why the %0D%0A is showing in get method in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am tryng to filter the columns in laravel with get method.

```
 {!! Form::open(['url'=>'/newjobseekers','method'=>'GET', 'class'=>'form', 'id'=>'search_data']) !!}
```

[image]
If I click submit button, then it show me the url like `http://localhost:8000/newjobseekers?fullname=0&previous_position_1=QC%0D%0A`. It should be end http://localhost:8000/newjobseekers?fullname=0&previous_position_1=QC without  %0D%0A , please guide me.Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your form or however you're building the query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do not have any space after `QC`.

The encoded `%0D%0A` you're seeing is equivalent to space and new line. 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

So be sure to trim it before it's passed to the form.